# Laplacian of a function restricted to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $f$ be a sufficiently smooth function on a manifold $S$. Let $M$ be a sub manifold of $S$. Can someone show how I can write  $\Delta^M f$ in terms of  $\Delta^{S}f$ ? ((i.e the relation between them))

PS: $\Delta^M$ and   $\Delta^{S}$ represent the Laplace-Beltrami operator the sub-manifold $M$ and the manifold S respectively.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let $e_1,\cdots e_m$ be local orthonormal basis on $M$ and $e_{m+1} , \cdots e_s$ be a local orthonormal frame normal to $M$. Let $\overline \nabla$ and $\nabla$ be the covariant derivative on $S$ and $M$ respectively.

$$\begin{split}
\Delta^S f &= \sum_{k=1}^s \overline\nabla^2 f(e_k, e_k) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m \overline\nabla^2 f(e_k,e_k) + \sum_{k=m+1}^s \overline \nabla ^2 f(e_k,e_k) 
\end{split}$$

The first term on the right can be written as

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^m \overline  \nabla^2 f(e_k,e_k) &= \sum_{k=1}^m e_k e_k f - \overline\nabla_{e_k} e_k f\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m e_ke_k f - \nabla_{e_k } e_k f - (\overline\nabla_{e_k}e_k)^\perp f \\
&= \Delta^M (f|_M) - \vec H f,
\end{split}$$

where $\vec H$ is the mean curvature vector of $M$ in $S$. So

$$(\Delta^S f)|_M = \Delta^M f|_M - \vec H f + \sum_{k=m+1}^s \overline \nabla ^2 f(e_k,e_k) .$$

It seems that not much can be said about the last term (which cannot be seem from $f|_M$).

Comment: I think that you have some mistake, because I have got $H\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu}$ in the intermediate align instead of $Hf$ @JohnMa

Comment: @As What's your $\nu$?

Comment: $\nu$ is unit outward normal of $M$ in $S$

Comment: But if $M$ is not of codimension one, there is no unit outward normal. @As

Comment: No, because of $M$ is of co-dimension one, this means that $M$ is nothing but $\partial S$, and in that case $\nu$ is the outward 'unit' normal of $\partial S$

Comment: @As : I am confused: are you assuming that $M$ is of codimension one? Even so I do not understand why "$M$ is nothing but $\partial S$"...

Comment: Cod=1 means dim M=dimS-1. I think that we don't have the same basic in Riemannian geometry. Anyway thank you very much for your help and I I get new thing I will write it on line.

Comment: Im so sorry because I was wrong and you have right. one more timeI'm so sorry.

Comment: Please, how can we simplify this formula if $S=\partial M$ ?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using $$\Delta f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{detg}}d _i (g^{ij}d_jf)$$
formula , where summation is occurring. Then, by picking a local orthonormal frame on $M$, and then extending to an orthonormal frame on $S$, I think you can simply ignore those derivatives in the above formula that involve directions other than those on $S$.

Since we are dealing with an intrinsic construction, this should work. Check with $R^2$ and $R^1$ case, for instance.